# Does Ubuntu have SMTP? If so, how can I see/edit configurations?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, ubuntu-10.04

I am having issues sending email from my Ubuntu OS.  I was told I should check my SMTP configuration.

How can I do that on Ubuntu and is there such a concept on this OS?

Comment: You really need to add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can have an MTA (providing SMTP services), but actual installation is configuration dependent. You can use `sudo apt-get install postfix` to install a popular and well regarded mail handler.  Be warned, running a poorly configured SMTP service can cause problems.

Comment: Keep in mind that installing the postfix package is not even close to everything you need to do to get a working email to the Internet.  If you are on a home connection, or firewalled business connection then delivery to anything outside of your own box is almost certainly blocked.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP configuration exists in your email client (Evolution, Thunderbird etc)

Comment: Thanks - how do I check which one I have? :)

Comment: How are you attempting to send email?

Comment: I am trying to send mail from a ruby on rails program.  I am invoking their library for sending mail, and it works fine, and tries to send it, but nothing gets sent.  So I figured it might be my SMTP

Comment: This is misleading.  Your mail client has a configuration to allow it to interact with an SMTP server, but those clients do not (themselves) act as an SMTP server.   The OP is actually needing a SMTP Server to process his application generated emails.

Answer (score 1):

When you send email from any type of system generally it can be done in 2 options:

1. Software contacts remote server, either on the LAN or outside of it.
2. Software uses a local SMTP server installed on the system.

Start with the inspection of the software you work on. Where is the configuration of the email there?

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to send data from a php based system I had a look around and I found a really useful how on [this blog](http://www.manu-j.com/blog/wordpress-exim4-ubuntu-gmail-smtp/75/), as I was sending from an internal server to our internal smtp server I just had to do step 1.